# Twitter Oauth Giving "The remote server returned an error: (401) "

Tags: oauth, twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I am using the Twitter OAuth to authenticate user and to show the user tweets on my site.

Following are the some Constants that are used for API:

public const string REQUEST_TOKEN = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
    public const string AUTHORIZE = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";
    public const string ACCESS_TOKEN = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";

Now when I am making a webrequest using the

new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

Then I am getting  error : "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

My webrequest uri is https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token?oauth_consumer_key=myConsumerkey&oauth_nonce=3403339&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1366792353&oauth_token=1372849567-3BtbvrvJ3HXl774InICgBz1T2jcLpif9xecxWmc&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=%2bLyQZwQwiNGJNP9uk591Hy4arfk%3d

So what is wron with this url. Please Healp me to get rid of this.

Thanks,
Dalvir

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending the oauth_verifier code that you received when the user authorized your app?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter applications not using the oauth_verifier will fail to complete the OAuth flow. If you're not receiving an oauth_verifier in your callback, verify that you're explicitly setting your oauth_callback on POST oauth/request_token.